# graph.windows.net is throwing 503 Server Unavailable error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

We are making differential query to azure graph endpoint for every 5 minutes. It was working perfectly for a month but now when we access the api it returns 503 service unavailable error. Even after 15 hours of retry (10 minutes gap between each retry) the service return same 503 unavailable response.

> The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503)
>   Server Unavailable.
>
> When looking at the fiddler, the response returned more detail on the
>   error.
>   {"odata.error":{"code":"Directory_ReplicaUnavailable","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The
>   preferred replica is unavailable. Please retry your request."}}}

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with Microsoft service side. After around 24 hours the API started working normally.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you hit the limits [and being throttled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling). Try to use back-off retry strategy instead of the constant time polling. There is nothing on the Azure health dashboard as well. You can try to see what is going on in the response using Fiddler, for example - likely the server unavailable is the generic error message.

Comment: Thanks Alex, fiddler provides me more info on the error. 

{"odata.error":{"code":"Directory_ReplicaUnavailable","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The preferred replica is unavailable. Please retry your request."}}}

By looking at the [solution provided here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling), removing the x-ms-replica-session header will work. As I am not sending the x-ms-replica-session header in request, I just retried the request but it didn't work.

Comment: To be honest, never had that error. Quick search revealed that it can be the datacenter service issue - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4505ff2d-1830-4c0d-9ffd-6b62f1c1b50f/graph-api-500-directoryreplicaunavailable-error?forum=WindowsAzureAD . One suggestion would be to see if that header is in the outgoing request - could you do that with a Fiddler?

Comment: No that header is not set when sending the request. I confirmed it with Fiddler.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to fix that issue. I think it can be intermittent, as i am not aware about any outages with that yet.I would try to not touch the database for say a half of a day and then try.